# Importance of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem

Tags: ring-theory, self-learning

I feel silly asking this, but what is the importance of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem in Algebra?

In **A First Course in Noncommutative Rings**, T.Y. Lam calls it "the cornerstone of non-commutative ring theory", and he goes on to list some very remarkable properties of modules over semisimple rings, some of which I list below :

- all modules are projective and injective,
- the ring itself is isomorphic to a product of matrix rings over division rings, and both these division rings and the size of these matrices are well defined (this is of course the Artin-Wedderburn theorem),
- group rings are semisimple (except for some special cases).

As someone who knows little to nothing about algebra, even I understand that these are terrific properties to have. **However, when do semisimple rings ever occur**? Do they only occur as group rings (not that this isn't very important)? Also, is it possible to know the division rings $D_i$ that appear in the theorem (apart from their characterisation as the endomporhism rings of the simple submodules of $R$) and the sizes $n_i$ of the matrices, say if

$$ R\simeq\prod_{i=1}^r\mathrm{Mat}_{n_i}(D_i)~? $$

Comment: I think it's cool that most of the basic results in Galois theory and the representation theory of finite groups can be proved using Artin-Wedderburn. See the lecture notes of Mitya Boyarchenko: [one](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/seminars/kottwitz/Galois.pdf), [two](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/seminars/kottwitz/Lecture2final.pdf).

Comment: You ask «is it possible to know the division rings that appear in the theorem?»: that of course depends on what you know about $R$!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Let's say $R$ is a group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ for a finite group $G$. EDIT: I guess this is an easy example, if one already knows the irreducible representations of $G$. My intent with this question is more along the lines of "what parts of the theorem are actually used"?

Comment: In that case all the $D_i$ are simply isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ :) Since $\mathbb C$ is an algebraically closed field, there are no non-trivial finite dimensional division algebras over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez .......... -_- yes

Comment: And there are [only so many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra#Associative_division_algebras) division algebras over $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @DylanMoreland I am unaware of the approach to Galois Theory you link to, I'll have a look at it (although I'm no good at Galois theory either ^^). Back to my original question, what are common semisimple rings other than group rings?

Comment: For other fields, the set of division algebras that appear in the decompositions of group algebras of finite groups generates a subgroup of the *Brauer group* (Wikipedia surely explains what this is; basically, a group which encodes division algebras) called the *Schur group* of the field. This has been studied for ages now, and a whole lot is known.

Comment: You ask «what are common semisimple rings other than group rings?» There are lots of constructions: twisted group algebras, cross-products, cyclic algebras, &c. The study and specially the construction of finite dimensional division algebras is an extremely important part of the classical theory of algebras—and an immensely beautiful subject. There is a nice peek into the theory in Pierce's book *Associative Algebras*, in a modern language. Already the study of quaternion algebras over fields is a huge field, (...)

Comment: (...) intimately related to pretty things like the Hasse-Minkowski principle and even very fashionable work connected to a couple of recent Fields medals and all.

Comment: So many nice, instructive comments. But why aren't they answers?

Comment: @DylanMoreland The links to Boyarchenko's lecture notes seem to be broken. Do you know another way to access these notes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring. The quotient $R/J(R)$, where $J(R)$ is the [Jacobson radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical), is the part of $R$ that acts nontrivially on the simple modules of $R$; said another way, it is the universal [semiprimitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprimitive_ring) quotient of $R$. If $R$ is Artinian, then $R/J(R)$ is Artinian semiprimitive, which turns out to be equivalent to semisimple, so we can apply Artin-Wedderburn to $R/J(R)$ and learn something important about our original ring $R$ (namely everything we can learn from looking at simple modules).

Comment: everything we can learn from looking at simple modules... except their extensions :)